# Concerning undetermined coefficients method if $f(x)=\sin(2x)\sin(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

for the non homogeneous higher order ODE 
$$y''-3y'+2y=\sin(2x)\sin(x) $$
if we want to solve using undetermined coefficients , can we assume that the particular solution has the form 
$$y_p(x)=(A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x))(C\sin(x)+D\cos(x))$$ ? 
if no then why we can not?

Comment: What's the homogeneous part?

Comment: y''-3y'+2y=sin(x)sin(2x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not assume that you get such a factorization. However, you can use trigonometric identities to get
$$
\sin(x)\sin(2x)=\frac12(\cos(x)-\cos(3x))
$$
and compute the particular solutions for each term separately.

---

Your friendly helper WolframAlpha gives the solution as follows, which one can then try to factorize,
\begin{align}
y(x) &= c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{2 x} - \frac{3}{20} \sin(x) + \frac{9}{260} \sin(3 x) + \frac1{20}\cos(x) + \frac{7}{260} \cos(3 x)\\
&=c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{2 x} 
\\&\qquad- \frac{30}{520}\sin(2x)\cos(x)+\frac{48}{520}\cos(2x)\sin(x)+\frac{20}{520}\cos(2x)\cos(x)+\frac{7}{520}\sin(2x)\sin(x)\\
&=c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{2 x} 
\\&\qquad+ \frac{10}{520}(-3\sin(2x)+2\cos(2x))\cos(x)+\frac{6}{520}(8\cos(2x)+\sin(2x))\sin(x)
\end{align}
at which point we see that the two factors are no further compatible.